# How to check if two objects properties match?

Tags: javascript

Lets say there are two objects but one object has property different from the other. Is there a way to figure out what properties match?

for example:

```
var objectOne = {
  boy: "jack",
  girl: "jill"
}


var objectTwo = {
  boy: "john",
  girl: "mary",
  dog: "mo"
}
```

edit: It should tell me `boy` and `girl` property name are found in both the objects.

Comment: Your example doesn't show much. What do you mean?

Comment: So you want a list of property *names* that are in both objects, without regard for what their *values* are? Shall we assume no object nesting?

Comment: @ nnnnnn . Yes Exactly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var in_both = [];
for (var key in objectOne) { // simply iterate over the keys in the first object
    if (Object.hasOwnProperty.call(objectTwo, key)) { // and check if the key is in the other object, too
        in_both.push(key);
    }
}
```

C.f. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty

Now, if you want to test if the values are the same, too, than simply add more code to the condition/body of the inner `if`.

Comment: Why not `objectTwo.hasOwnProperty(key)`? How does `.call()` help? (Interesting choice to link to the *German* documentation.)

Comment: @nnnnnn, `objectTwo` could have its own item `hasOwnProperty`. Not using `.call` is an easy attack vector, though it's unlikely to cause more than a DOS. Oops, did not notice that I linked the wrong language. You may simply edit the question next time.

Comment: Fair enough. I guess in my own code I'm generally dealing with objects I've created myself, where there would definitely not be an own `hasOwnProperty`. But your way works for any object.

Answer (score 2):

Using [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

```
Object.keys(objectOne).filter(k => Object.hasOwnProperty.call(objectTwo, k))
```

Comment: Your code solves the question in quadratic time when linear time would do. Do not do that in production!

Comment: Here is linear :P

Comment: You should use `hasOwnProperty`, because `null` and `undefined` might be valid values.

Comment: You're welcome. Your one-line solution is the prettiest, IMO. No needless (explicit) loops.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Object.keys` and use `Array.prototype.reduce` to loop through once and list out the common keys - see demo below:

```js
var objectOne={boy:"jack",girl:"jill"};
var objectTwo={boy:"john",girl:"mary",dog:"mo"};

var result = Object.keys(objectOne).reduce(function(p,c){
  if(c in objectTwo)
    p.push(c);
  return p;
},[]);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find out which keys match given two objects, you could loop through all of the keys of the objects using a `for... in` loop. In my function, it will loop through the keys and return an array of all of the matching keys in the two objects.

```js
let objectOne = {
  boy: "jack",
  girl: "jill"
}

let objectTwo = {
  boy: "john",
  girl: "mary",
  dog: "mo"
}

function matchingKeys (obj1, obj2) {
  let matches = [];
  let key1, key2;
  
  for (key1 in obj1) {
    for (key2 in obj2) {
      if ( key1 === key2) {
        matches.push(key1);
      }
    }
  }
  return matches
}

const result = matchingKeys(objectOne, objectTwo);
console.log(result)
```

Comment: @Kay - I find this easy enough to read, other than the weird mix of `var`, `let`, and undeclared-and-therefore-global variables.

Comment: @Kay Thank you for the feedback, you're right, it can be done linear time. I tried to improve the readability, but I keep the spirit of my original solution.

Comment: @nnnnn Thank you for the feedback, I made my variables consistent. You da best 

Comment: The `key1` and `key2` variables are still global, and - more importantly - your code doesn't actually run...

Comment: @nnnnn Fixed my answer - thanks again for the heads up.

Comment: @JoeKarlsson. I liked your answer too. It's very simple and understandable.

Comment: @Deke - Thank you so much! Glad it was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try this on for size:

```js
function compare(obj1, obj2) {
    // get the list of keys for the first object
    var keys = Object.keys(obj1);

    var result = [];

    // check all from the keys in the first object
    // if it exists in the second object, add it to the result
    for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
        if (keys[i] in obj2) {
            result.push([keys[i]])
        }           
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't better than some solutions here, but I thought I'd share:

```js
function objectHas(obj, predicate) {
  return JSON.stringify(obj) === JSON.stringify({ ...obj, ...predicate })
}
```